# Vector adds element, but shortly after removes it

Tags: java

First, my code (shortened):

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class GameField {

    private Vector rooms = new Vector();

    public void generateRooms() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rooms.add(new Room(x, y, width, height));
        }
    }
}
```

I know the class Vector is generic, but we haven't learned those yet and we should use it like this.

When I call the method `generateRooms()` it doesn't add ten rooms as expected, but adds one room every loop and removes the room again if it comes to the beginning of the loop.

At the end, I only have one room in the Vector, instead of ten.

Why is this so? Is it because I don't use generic types or what else causes this behaviour?

Comment: Your code looks fine - how are you checking the contents of the `rooms` structure?

Comment: Could you show us what the Room class looks like?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Setting a break point to the loop and look what it does exactly?

Comment: Print the size of the vector before breaking from the loop and try to debug

Comment: Did you try vector.addElement() ? Just in case it is running in multi threaded env

Comment: print `rooms.size()` after loop , and see if it is 10 or not

Comment: I have now tried debugging it. On every loop the `rooms` variable got a new ID. I think this is why it loses the added room... Does anybody know why it does that?

My `Room` class is a very simple class: It has the four membervariables `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`, the Custom-Constructor (as showed above) and the Setter and Getter for the members.

Comment: I have also tries the method `addElement()`, but got the same result.

Comment: As the code stands it's impossible to diagnose, because there's nothing here that would do anything other than add elements to the vector. There's something you're not showing us causing the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I make the `generateRooms` function return the `room` vector  , and it works OK :

```
public class Room {

    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    public Room(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
class Main {

    private Vector rooms = new Vector();

    public Vector generateRooms() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rooms.add(new Room(1 * i, 2, 3, 4));
        }
        return rooms;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        Vector r = m.generateRooms();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Room room = (Room) r.get(i);
            System.out.println(room.x + "   " + room.y + "   " + room.width + "    " + room.height);
        }
    }
}
```